# How to convert a key from old to new format?

Tags: keys, public-key

So I was curious how to do that. I wasn't able to find any tools online to do that.

Comment: PUB_K1 to EOS format key

Answer (score 0):

See here for an online converter: https://wax.bloks.io/wallet/utilities/format-keys

Comment: Thanks, but this one converts PUB_K1 to EOS format key, I need to convert EOS to PUB_K1

Answer (score 0):

with eosjs the PublicKey and PrivateKey objects have the ability to convert to string or legacy string:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/99d21e8f2bce7eb1c31c66de06f1e1454344f2d2/src/PublicKey.ts#L37-L45

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/99d21e8f2bce7eb1c31c66de06f1e1454344f2d2/src/PrivateKey.ts#L40-L47

or here:
https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/API-Reference/classes/_publickey_.publickey

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/API-Reference/classes/_privatekey_.privatekey/#methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringToPublicKey` function from the `EOSJS` library.

Assuming [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/) is installed, you can run the following commands in your terminal.

```
npm install eosjs
node
Welcome to Node.js v16.10.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> app = require(‘eosjs’)
> const key = app.Numeric.stringToPublicKey('EOSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’)
> app.Numeric.publicKeyToString(key)
```